# Discord Error that i dont know what is this

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make discord.py selfbot tried

it doesnt work error is:

```
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\selfbot\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .webhook import Webhook
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .async_ import *
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..http import Route, handle_message_parameters, MultipartParameters, HTTPClient, json_or_text
ImportError: cannot import name 'handle_message_parameters' from 'discord.http' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py)
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\selfbot>
```

my code is this also i dont very know Python just trying to make selfbot for something that really helpful for me so thanks for helping

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

commandsPrefix = '!'
token = "awesometoken"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commandsPrefix, self_bot=True)

bot.run(token)
```

```
pip3 install discord
pip3 install discord.py-self
```

Answer (score 1):

The discord.py-self package broke your discord.py installation. Get rid of it (as well as any other discord-related package) and force-reinstall dpy.

Selfbotting is against Discord's TOS anyway and will get you banned, so no one will help you installing that package (or anything else that is selfbot-related for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

It seems `pip3 install discord.py-self` overwrites your discord.py library. To fix it `pip uninstall discord.py-self` then `pip install -U discord.py`.

If you need both you can use something like venv or virtualenv and install the self bot there